# Validate file extensions match approved list

Tags: c#, regex, linq, list

I have a list of list of files that I want to against a list of approved extensions.
The list of approved extensions may be either

- Mandatory or Optional

I need to handle two cases

- Check that the list of files contains all mandatory extensions
- The list of files may only contain extensions in the approved list

Have been trying with regex because some cases can be grouped together. For example `.docx` and `.doc` treated as the same

Here is what I have so far (pseudo code)

```
List<string[]> approvedExt = new List<string[]>();
// M - Mandatory 
// O - Optional 
approvedExt.Add(new[] { "pdf", "M" });
approvedExt.Add(new[] { "(docx|doc)", "M" }); //Handle as one case
approvedExt.Add(new[] { "(txt)", "O" });

//Example list
List<string> fileList = new List<string>();
fileList.Add("123.pdf");
fileList.Add("123.txt");
fileList.Add("123.xlsx");
fileList.Add("123.pdf");

//pseudo code
For each ext in approvedExt (that are Mandatory)
{
    bool checkMandatoryExt = Any file match?
    //Example code I have seen
    fileList.All(f => System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(f, pattern, System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
}
if (!checkMandatoryExt)
{
    //Handle Error
}

for each file in fileList
{
    bool allApprovedExt = Any patterns match?
}
if (!allApprovedExt)
{
    //Handle Error
}
```

The example file list above would fail 2 cases

- Contains a `.xlsx` file (Not in the approved ext list)
- Does contain neither a `.docx` nor `.doc` file (Mandatory extension not in the file list)

I would like to be able to pass a list of files names and a list of approved extensions and return `true`/`false` if the list files passes the two checks above.

Thank you

Comment: Where's the question?

Comment: Have updated the end of the question.

Comment: Don't use regular expressions to get the extension from the file name. Use [Path.GetExtension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getextension(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I would solve it (pseudo code):

```
public class Condition
{
    public bool Mandatory {get;set;}
    public string[] Extensions {get;set;}
}

// ...

//NOTE: includes the . before the extension
public string[] GetExtensions(IEnumerable<string> files)
{
    return files.Select(f => Path.GetExtension(f).ToLower()??"").Distinct().ToArray();
}

public bool AllConditionsOk(string[] fileNamesToCheck, Condition[] conditions)
{
    //Extract Extension only (e.g. Path.GetExtension)
    string[] extensions = GetExtensions(fileNamesToCheck);

    //Check if any existing extension is not allowed
    foreach(string extension in extensions)
    {
        if(!conditions.Any(c => c.Extensions.Contains(extension)))
            return false;
    }

    //Check if every mandatory condition is fulfilled
    foreach(Condition condition in conditions.Where(c => c.Mandatory))
    {
         if(!condition.Extensions.Any(e => extensions.Contains(e)))
             return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Or if you prefer a short version:

```
return extensions.Any(extension => !conditions.Any(c => c.Extensions.Contains(extension))) &&
       conditions.Where(c => c.Mandatory)
                 .All(condition => condition.Extensions.Any(e => extensions.Contains(e)));
```

Comment: He has a list of filenames `fileList(){"123.pdf",
"123.txt","123.xlsx"
"123.pdf")`

Comment: @DmitriyKovalenko the example provided by Spacko is, as he clearly states, pseudo code as well. Changing the collection type will most likely not be an unsolvable problem for him (string[] --> List<string>) and has no influence on the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check extensions in **list of filenames** contains in extension list you can do it like this:

```
foreach(var file in filelist)
{
    approvedExt.Contains(file.split(".").Last();
}
```

Comment: No, you should use `Path.GetExtension`. Consider, for example, the path `C:\My.Files\datafile`. Your method would say that the file extension is `Files\datafile`.

Comment: As I understand he has only list of filenames - strings.

Comment: Yes only a string list of filenames. My current difficulty is how to take the list of approved extensions and split them by mandatory/optional. Above I was testing with a List<string[]> to store the approved ext list, but I dont know if there are better methods to store and then filter list pproved ext list by mandatory/optional